# For an L-structure $M$, and a formula $\phi$, in which of the cases does $M \models \phi(x/2)$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

For

a) $\phi(x)$ is $(\forall y(y=1+1 \implies x=y))$

b) $\phi(x)$ is $(\forall x(x=1+1 \implies x=y))$

The answer is supposed to be a) but I don't know why. I guess I don't fully understand the notation $M \models \phi(x/2)$ and am therefore not really sure what I am meant to be doing. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\phi(x/2)$ means the formula obtained fron $\phi(x)$ (with $x$ free) when the number $2$ is assigned as value to the variable $x$.

Thus, the question :

> in which case $M \vDash \phi(x/2)$,

often written as : $M \vDash \phi(x)[2]$, ask if the formula $\phi(x)$ is true in $M$ when the value $2$ is assigned to the free variable $x$.

Now, for

*a)* when $\phi(x)$ is $∀y(y=1+1 \rightarrow x=y)$

we have that :

> $∀y(y=1+1 \rightarrow x=y)[2]$

is $∀y(y=1+1 \rightarrow 2=y)$, which is *true* in $\mathbb N$.

For

*b)* when $\phi(x)$ is $∀x(x=1+1 \rightarrow x=y)$

instead, $x$ is not *free* in $\phi(x)$ and thus we cannot assign $2$ s value to it.

Thus, $\phi(x)[2]$ is simply $\phi(x)$ which is not *true* : it is enough to assign $1$ to $y$ and we get : $∀x(x=1+1 \rightarrow x=1)$.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thank you very much.